# Mysql dump error trying to create an export from my database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, debian, bitnami, database-backups

I am trying to export my database running this command :

```
sudo mysqldump -h wordpress -u root -p bitnami_wordpress >rescue2.database.sql
```

and got this error :

> mysqldump: Got error: 2005: “Unknown MySQL server host ‘wordpress’
> (-2)” when trying to connect

I am on a Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64

Thanks for helping it’s been 2 weeks I am searching for…

Comment: `-h` option specifies the name or IP address of the host where MySQL server works. But `wordpress` seems to be a name of the database to be backed up.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Akina, -h specifies the IP Address of the host,
for example localhost or any local ip on which the mysql server might be running.

Refer below command for further usage.

```
mysqldump -u [user name] –p [password] [options] [database_name] [tablename] > [dumpfilename.sql]
```

or:

```
mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
```

where the `[OPTIONS]` can be (only some often used):

- -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
- -p, --password[=name]
- -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.

for a complete list you can do: `mysqldump --help`, or take a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: More correct (IMHO): After `-h` you need to specify a hostname or an IP-address. A hostname (can) resolve to an IP-address (using [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file called `wp-config.php` at the top level of your WordPress installation.  It contains lines like these:

```php
define( 'DB_NAME', 'my_wordpress' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'EmileCantero' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'some_secret_password' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'whatever.example.com' );
```

Use that information in your `mysqldump` command like so

```sh
mysqldump -h whatever.example.com -u EmileCantero -p my_wordpress >rescue2.database.sql
```

Avoid running this as root (avoid `sudo`) unless you cannot get it to work any other way.

A better way for most WP site operators: use one of the free WordPress backup plugins.

Comment: Thanks O.Jones :) Did it then got the error : Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)" when t
rying to connect

Comment: The instructions I gave only work reliably when you run them logged in to the same machine where your WordPress web server runs. Use a backup plugin.

Comment: Yes understood but cannot run any plugin actually the website is showing me a database error so impossible to access admin wp

Comment: Sound like my password is wrong:

Comment: According to your coment I ran sudo mysqldump -h exemple.com -u root bitnami_wordpress --single-transaction >rescue5.database.sql
 then got error : mysqldump: Got error: 1698: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" when trying to connect